# Ajax sends 2 POST requests...I don't have any live() event handlers

Tags: jquery

I want to send one of two async requests based on a click event (login and register). 
My click handler is sending 2 POST requests for each respective click (2 login requests, or 2 register requests).  I know that event handlers created by the live method can cause this problem.  The thing is, I don't have any in my script.  I've replaced them with .delegate()

Here it is...

```
 //ajax registration.  
$('input#register_submit').click(function(event){
    $.post("/register_async/", $('div#register_side form').serialize(), 
        function(data){
            $.each(data,function(){
            if(this.user_status==1){
                $('#header-top').html('<ul><li>Hi,'+ this.user_fname + '&nbsp | </li><li><a href="">Log Out</a></li></ul>');
                $('#post_login_modal').dialog("close");

                $('input[name=preview]').unbind('click');

                $('a.login').unbind('click');
                $('li a.account').unbind('click');  

            }
            else{
                 $('p#login_title').text('There are errors in your form').css("color","red");

            //redirect upon failed registration
            //window.location='{{site}}register';

            }
        });         
        }
    ,'json');
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
    });


//ajax login...just for this page right now  
$('input#login_submit_btn').click(function(event){
    $.post("/login_async/", $('div#login_side form').serialize(), 
        function(data){
            $.each(data,function(){
            if(this.user_status==1){
                $('#header-top').html('<ul><li>Hi,'+ this.user_fname + '&nbsp | </li><li><a href="">Log Out</a></li></ul>');
                $('#post_login_modal').dialog("close");

                $('a.login').unbind('click');
                $('li a.account').unbind('click');

                //specific to upload page.  removes login/register modal window click handler
                $('input[name=preview]').unbind('click');

                $('#contact_btn').unbind('click');
                $('#contact_btn').click(function(){
                $('#contact_renter').dialog('open');
                    });

                $('#save_btn').unbind('click');
                $('#save_btn').click(function(){
                    $('#save_modal').dialog('open');
                });


                $('span.anon').unbind('click');
                $('li.star_rater span.last').click(function(e){
                    $('#rate_modal').dialog('open');
                    e.stopPropagation();

                $('#flag span').click(function(event){
                    $('#rate_modal').dialog('close');
                    $('#flag_modal').dialog('open');
                    event.stopPropagation();

                });     

                //change rating/reporting, saving favorites, and contact based on ajax response 

            });

            }
            else{
                $('p#login_title').text('That email/password is invalid').css("color","red");
            }
            //prevents user from saving post as favorite if he has already done so
            if(this.user_favorite==1){
                $('#stats li:eq(3)').remove();
                $('<li><span id="saved">Saved<span></li>').appendTo('ul#stats');
            };  
            //prevents user from rating/reporting more than once
            if(this.flag_record==1){
                $('.star_rater span.anon').remove();
                $('<span class="voted"> Rated! </span>').appendTo('li.star_rater');
            };  

        });
    },'json');
    return false;
    });
```

To deal with closing all modal windows throughout my site, I also have this event handler:

```
   $('body').delegate(".ui-widget-overlay","click", function(e) {
$("#rate_modal,#contact_renter,#save_modal, #login_modal,#post_login_modal,#flag_modal,#save_success,#flag_success,#mail_success,#rating_success,#delete_note").dialog("close");
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I could have sworn, after I changed the live handler to delegate, it worked.

Comment: Have you tried returning false from your delegate function? I don't think stopPropagation() is enough.

Comment: just tried. it didn't get it done...

Comment: What happens when you remove the delegate() ?

Comment: doh, I should have tried that.  Well I just removed delegate() and the problem persisted.

Comment: strange... what does `$('input#register_submit').data('events').click` show in the console? Does it list 2 click handlers? If so, are you sure your JS isn't being included twice?

Comment: The sad part here is that i'm totally ignorant when it comes to debugging.  I have no idea how to do that

Comment: No problem. If you're using Firefox, go get [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com). It will provide a nice Javascript console when you click the firebug icon in the browser status bar. You can also use the built-in error console (Ctrl-Shift-J.) If you're using IE, F12 will open Developer Tools which will also give you a console in the Script tab.

Comment: Once you have a console, enter `$('input#register_submit').data('events').click` into it. It should output an array, like `[ Object { type="click", guid=37} ]`. Each Option listed in that array will be a jQuery click handler. If you're using Firebug, you can then click on those objects to drill down and see what each of them is. Firebug will take you to the actual JS code that will be run when that click event is fired. If you have more than one Object listed in that array, you have multiple click handlers registered for that element, and you have to figure out why.

Comment: Hi itchy, I use firebug, but I'm unfamiliar with performing searches within console.  I've tried to search for the jquery object in the search bar.  I'm not quite sure where to input the text otherwise

Comment: You see the >>> prompt in firebug's console tab? Just enter `$('input#register_submit').data('events').click` there and hit enter.

Comment: Is it in the watch sectoin? It is showing an array with two objects (each with a differnet guid)

Comment: If you see a Watch section, you're in the Script tab, not the Console tab. Anyway, if you're only assigning one click handler to those elements, that means your JS is being loaded twice somehow. Do you have 2 script tags sourcing the same JS?

Comment: i don't...this has been a rough one

Comment: Where do those 2 click handlers for #register_submit go? To the same code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't think of this before. If those click handlers are attached to `<input type="submit">` buttons, then you're submitting the forms twice: once for the click events, through AJAX, and again through the onsubmit events of the forms.

Change your `.click()` functions to `.submit()` and attach them to the form elements rather than the submit buttons.

```
$('form#form1').submit( function() {
    // your existing code
    return false;
}
```

Either that, or change those submit buttons into actual `<button>`s, or `<a>`s, or something.

Comment: This really seemed like the answer.  I tried to both submit the form and change the buttons to other elements.  Neither approach worked.

Comment: Hmm... You may have to post your entire HTML and JS. Or if you've got a way I can look at it online, that would be even better.

Comment: Good lord almightt, I was loading the js twice.  I hate myself

Comment: THanks for your help itchy.  You pointed me in the right direction

Comment: Glad you figured it out... it was bothering me :)